# Finding of possible combinations of matrix elements depending on the addition of rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Lets take an example of **2x2** matrix. The intital values of elements are unknown so assuming it as variables like **x,y,a & b** would be a good start. The addition of rows and columns are known, such as,

```
x y = 3
a b = 7
= =
4 6
```

The equations generated are,

```
x+y=3 - (1)
x+a=4 - (2)
a+b=7 - (3)
y+b=6 - (4)
```

Here, 3 and 7 are addition of rows and 4 and 6 are addition of columns.
One of the possible combination here is,

```
1 2 = 3
3 4 = 7
= =
4 6
```

Is there any **method** that would help calculating the combination of elements in matrix that would **`satisfy the addition of rows and columns`**, when the initial values of matrix elements are **unknown**?

Answer (score 0):

These are linear equations, so classical Gaussian elimination should do the trick.
Apart from that, you can apply any way you know for solving systems of linear equations.

Comment: Thanks anyways! I figured this out by guessing the numbers from 1 in ascending order to the least number among sum of rows and columns. In this way, the loop goes on finding the possible combinations.